# Extract string between two delimiters in Python dataframe

Tags: python

I am trying to extract values between `:` and `-` from this below

```
>>> all_cancers.iloc[:,3]
0        chr1:100414771-100414772
1          chr1:10506157-10506158
2        chr1:109655506-109655507
3        chr1:113903257-113903258
4        chr1:117598869-117598870
```

I tried `re.findall('\:(.*?)\-', all_cancers.iloc[:,3].astype(str))` to do this but it generates the following error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

What is missing here?

Comment: You can do it without regular expression `s = "chr1:100414771-100414772" ; s[s.index(":") + 1: s.rindex("-")]`

Comment: I want to extract across column values not just a string.

Comment: Try this `all_cancers.iloc[:,3].apply(lambda s: s[s.index(":") + 1: s.rindex("-")])`

Comment: I really bad at pandas, so my explanation won't be any good. I believe that you will get better answer. In my code sample I've just called [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and passed there [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) which slice every string from index of first occurrence of `:` char *([`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index))* to index of last occurrence of `-` *([`str.rindex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex))*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern,

```
In [33]: re.match(r'.*:(.*)-',"chr1:100414771-100414772").group(1)
Out[33]: '100414771'
```

In datafame you can do with `apply` + `lambda`

```
all_cancers.iloc[:,3].apply(lambda x: re.match(r'.*:(.*)-', x).group(1))
```

Using `extract`

```
all_cancers.iloc[:,3].str.extract(r'.*:(.*)-')
```

*(credit: OlvinRoght's comment)*

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aE5PJFRfzoXderr6)